# When I return by value from an assignment operator, firstly what is the mechanism and basis of calling the copy constructor?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, return-by-reference, return-by-value

Consider this piece of code and its output:

```
class test {    
    int a, b;

    public:
        test (int a, int b) : a(a), b(b) { cout << "Const" << endl;}

        test (const test & t) {
            cout << "Copy constructor" << endl;
            cout << "Being copied to = " << this << " from " <<  &t << endl;
            if (&t == this) {
                cout << "returning" << endl;
               return;
            }
            this->a = t.a;
            this->b = 6;//t.b;
        }

        test operator=(const test & in) {
        cout << "Assignment operator" << endl;
        this->a = in.a;
        this->b = in.b;
        cout << "Being written to = " << this << " from  "<< &in << endl;
        return *this;
    }

    test get () {
        test l = test (3, 3);
        cout << "Local return " << &l << endl;
        return l;
    }

    void display () {
        cout << a << " " << b << endl;
    }
};

int main () {
    int i = 5, &ref = i;
    test t(1,1), u(2,2);

    u = t.get();
    cout << "u address" << &u <<endl;
    //cout << "u ka = " << &u << endl;
    u.display();   
}
```

Output:

```
Const
Const
Const
Local return 0x7fff680e5ab0
Assignment operator
Being written to = 0x7fff680e5a90 from  0x7fff680e5ab0
Copy constructor
Being copied to = 0x7fff680e5a80 from 0x7fff680e5a90
u address0x7fff680e5a90
3 3
```

I know the way to return from an assignment is by reference, but I was trying to understand how this works since I am a beginner to C++.
What is the address 0x7fff680e5a80 ? Where is this coming from ? Which object is calling the copy constructor here ? I would expect u (address 0x7fff680e5a90) to call it.

Comment: Can you fix your newlines? It'll be easier to explain your output.

Comment: Also you should add the address of this in the non-copy constructor, that makes the output easier to read.

Comment: The correct signature should be `test& operator=(const test & in);`!

Comment: Kudos for your keen observations on the behavior. This is how you learn the best stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets follow your code (I modified your constructor to dump the constructed this).

First you isntantiate t and u.

```
Const at 0x7fffffffdeb0
Const at 0x7fffffffdea0
```

Then you call t.get, which initializes l.

```
Const at 0x7fffffffdec0
```

You then return l.

```
Local return 0x7fffffffdec0
```

The copy constructor that would normally happen at this point is elided.

```
Assignment operator from l to u
Being written to = 0x7fffffffdea0 from  0x7fffffffdec0
```

Then you are returning the assignment by value (you should return it by reference), so you copy from u to an output value that isn't stored (0x7fffffffde90 from u)

```
Copy constructor
Being copied to = 0x7fffffffde90 from 0x7fffffffdea0
```

And then you print u.

```
u address0x7fffffffdea0
```

Inside T.

To get rid of the confusing (and unessisary copy) you should return by reference when you do any assignment operator:

```
test& operator=(const test & in);
```

Comment: I follow the part till the assignment and then since I return by value, we reach the copy constructor. Shouldn't it then be 
Copy constructor
Being copied to = 0x7fffffffdea0 from 0x7fffffffdea0

I mean what is 0x7fffffffde90 ? This seems like an address of something irrelevant.

Comment: To be a bit clearer, you replace "test operator=(const test & in)" with "test & operator=(const test & in)". Methods usually return a *copy* of their output (thus the call to the copy constructor). You want to return a *reference* in order to save time and to prevent strange behaviors.

Comment: @YvesDubois I've added that to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Your assignment operator is incorrect:

```
    test operator=(const test & in) {
```

You should return by reference:

```
    test &operator=(const test & in) {
```

The object at `0x7fff680e5a80` is a prvalue temporary object of type `test` that is returned from your (incorrect) assignment operator and immediately discarded:

```
test operator=(const test & in) {
    cout << "Assignment operator" << endl;
    this->a = in.a;
    this->b = in.b;
    cout << "Being written to = " << this << " from  "<< &in << endl;
    return *this;
}   //     ^-- copy constructor is called here
```

You can check this by taking an rvalue reference to the return value of the assignment operator:

```
auto &&temp = (u = t.get());
std::cout << "Address of temp: " << &temp << std::endl;  // prints 0x7fffffffde90
```

Comment: Yes I understand that, and I've mentioned this in my summary as well. But I want to understand the mechanism of this, since I'm a beginner.

Comment: @user2910606 you should learn how to obey the rules before you start trying to break them! I've added some explanation above.

Comment: @ecatmur imho, its valid to question the rules, if only to understand them better.

Comment: Thanks @ecatmur for the response.

I still have a follow-up question. When you say copy constructor is called here, which object calls the copy constructor ? From the output it looks the object at 0x7fffffffde90 calls it. But 0x7fffffffde90 is the address of which object ?

Comment: The object at `0x7fffffffde90 ` does not have a name in your program, because you discard it without forming a reference to it.  See above.